# C++ non-static data member initializers of lambda function members with the 'this' object

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-studio-2013, lambda

I have an understanding problem with C++11, Visual Studio 2013 (probably not a Visual Studio problem) and non-static data member initializers of lambda function members.

```
class Test {
private:
    int _number;

    int _numberGetter() {
        return this->_number; // OK
    }

public:
    std::function<int(void)> NumberTest1 = [&]()->int {
        return this->_number;  // error: 'this' cannot be used inside the body of this lambda
    };
    //std::function<int(void)> NumberTest2 = Test::_numberGetter;
    std::function<int(void)> NumberTest3;
    std::function<int(void)> NumberTest4;
    std::function<int(void)> NumberTest5;
    std::function<int(void)> NumberTest6;

    Test() : NumberTest3(&Test::_numberGetter) { } // OK
    Test() : NumberTest4([&]()->int {
        return this->_number; // OK
    }) { }
    Test() {
        NumberTest5 = &Test::_numberGetter; // OK
    }
    Test() { 
        NumberTest6 = [&]()->int {
            return this->_number; // OK
        };
    }
};
```

Why can't I directly initialize the std::function NumberTest1 with a lambda function, in which the object instance this is.
Maybe it's because the lambda function will be directly complied, other then the normal member function _numberGetter, and in this moment the instance object this is not avalible. But this is only a presumption. Against this presumption is that NumberTest1 is not a constant and should only avalible from a class instance.
Maybe this is possible and I have only a little mistake in my code.

EIDT 1:
Visual Studio Version:
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4
.Net Version 4.5.51641

Comment: The compiler doesn't issue any errors for initialization of `NumberTest1` but does issue errors for two of the constructors marked as `OK` and the initialization of `NumberTest2`. Would be helpful to include the versioning information in the VS about box (including service packs). You should also double check the code since there are discrepancies and syntax errors in the code you posted.

Comment: There are several problems in your code. For example: `std::function<int(void)> NumberTest2 = Test::_numberGetter;` This is NOT OK. First, you cannot take the address of a non-static member function without `&`. Then, it needs an additional argument (`this`) to become a nullary function. The ctors have similar issues. Once removed, the remaining NSDMI that uses `this` is accepted by clang++ and g++. *"probably not a Visual Studio problem"* It probably is.

Comment: Once you fix all the problems mentioned in the comments above, VC++ will also compile the code with the initialization of `NumberTest1`. The error you're seeing is from IntelliSense, which you can safely ignore in this case.

Comment: NumberTest2 error OK. I understand this but NumberTest1... 
@Captain Obvlious you wrote that the compiler doesn't issue any errors for initialization. Where did you test this? Or did you know this?

Comment: I compiled it with version 18.00.21005.1 of the Microsoft compiler.

Comment: @bogdan you was right. After I fixed my other problem, temporary code as commend, the NumberTest1 is still red underlined and says the same error message but the compiler write that the code compiled successful.

Comment: @Heinrich However, don't make a habit out of ignoring IntelliSense errors - sometimes *it* will be right and the main VC++ compiler will be wrong. When in doubt, try other compilers as well, Clang for example - online compilers are very convenient to use these days.